# How to modify content with CSS?

Tags: html, css

> **WARNING: 
>   I do not recommend anyone to do this. It's an ugly hack.**

I've got the code (minimized for the example)

```
<div id="somecontent">
    <a name="content"></a>
    Content to be changed
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zalun/o733uyvs/

I'd like to change the "Content to be changed" with CSS. 
Is this even possible (all ugly hacks included)?
It's easy when HTML is modified (<span> added) as in second block in mentioned fiddle.

Comment: And where is your problem?

Comment: Why not use JS, its build for this kind of manipulations?

Comment: @SamKool As there is a lot of such elements on the page which is already JS heavy.

Comment: @Troyer The change I've suggested in the first block (JSFiddle) is aligned to the right, which is no fun.

Comment: Not sure what's up with the negative votes, indeed it's wrong what he is trying to do, but what if he is not having access to html files? It happens when you work in corporate world where you have to do such things because of lack of access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: What you are trying to do is not recommended. I am providing you
>   a solution because I think you do not have access to source HTML or
>   your content is generated dynamically. I would still suggest you too
>   either change the source file or modify the DOM node using JavaScript.

I would say No and Yes.

**Why No?**

That's a text node. You cannot manipulate DOM nodes using CSS. You need to use JavaScript for that.

**Why Yes? (Using ugly hacks), How?**

Using `content` property as you are already using, but you cannot change the DOM, so you can make it super ugly like

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o733uyvs/6/)**

```
#somecontent {
  color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

#somecontent a:before {
  content: "My new content";
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

---

JavaScript Solution :

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o733uyvs/7/)

```
// You'll see text flicker
var t = document.getElementById('somecontent');
t.textContent  = 'New Text';
```

Comment: Nice! I haven't been thinking about changing color for hiding stuff. 
Certainly I know changing content with CSS is asking for trouble, but that's not a problem in this particular execution.